# Outlook Subfolder Attachment saving - powershell COM

Tags: powershell, outlook

```
#file path
$filepath = “c:\test\”


#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


#you'll get a popup in outlook at this point where you pick the folder you want to scan
$f = $n.pickfolder()

#date string to search for in attachment name
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd


#now loop through them and grab the attachments
$f.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.filename
    $a = $_.filename
    If ($a.Contains($date)) {
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a))
      }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help with this above script, it actually runs and writes to host but the attachments dont appear in the drive folder as they should, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just copied the script and havent noticed it just saves attachements where the name contains the current date in yyyyMMdd format this is what you would do if you want to save all attachements:

```
#file path
$filepath = “c:\test\”


#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


#you'll get a popup in outlook at this point where you pick the folder you want to scan
$f = $n.pickfolder()

#now loop through them and grab the attachments
$f.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.filename
    $a = $_.filename
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after all i didnt delete the useless get-date. I essentially want to have emails sent to a subfolder but then each attachment print as it lands in the subfolder, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: @Royston i dont know, if you can find a way to make outlook safe the file to a folder as it comes in you could register an event handler for the directory and print them that way but you will have to figure out yourself. This is out of scope of the topic though. If my answer solved your question remember to accept it.